# Shell scripting: Iteration over files and modyfying filenames

Tags: bash, shell

Scenario: I use a simple function to minify and compress JS files during the deployment like this:

```
for i in public/js/*.js; do uglifyjs --overwrite --no-copyright "$i"; done
```

The problem with this approach is that it minifies and overwrites original files. I would like to somehow introduce a **versioning of minified JS and CSS** files.

Let's say I have a variable with the version: "123". How to modify my script to write files with this version? It should work with CSS and JS files like this:

```
style.css -> style.123.css
script.js -> script.123.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should work in sh too:

```
VERSION=321; for i in public/js/*.js; do NEW=$(echo $i | sed s/\\./.$VERSION./) ; cp $i $NEW; uglifyjs --overwrite --no-copyright $NEW; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
VERSION=123; for i in public/js/*.js; do REV=${i/%.js/.${VERSION}.js}; cp "${i}" "${REV}"; uglifyjs --overwrite --no-copyright "${REV}"; done
```

`REV=${i/%.js/.${VERSION}.js}` replaces the last occurrence of ".js" by ".123.js".

Comment: When using with node.js (child_process exec) I gen an error: "/bin/sh: Bad substitution". Any chance of a quick fix?

Comment: @Pono: `REV=${i/%.js/.${VERSION}.js}` is a bash string manipulation. That's why `/bin/sh` could work. Replace `#!/bin/sh` in your script by `#!/bin/bash`. Or replace `REV=${i/%.js/.${VERSION}.js}` by a sed call: `REV="$(echo $i | sed 's#^\(.*\)\.\([a-z]\+\)$#\1.'$VERSION'.\2#')"`

Answer (score 0):

This is a silly approach. Use a version control tool for versioning your sources.

But of course, you're right not to want to modify the files in place.

Call your source files `foo.src.js` (or whatever). (Keep the last suffix `.js` so your editor recognizes the language). Then have a build step which produces `foo.js`.  When you're developing you can have a "null compile" step which just copies `foo.src.js` to `foo.js`. When you make a release, then the copy step is changed to do the `uglifyjs` instead of a copy. Either way, you never edit the generated `foo.js` by hand, of course, even when it is just a copy.  You might want to, instead of just copying, add a comment on top "generated file, do not edit".

The exact details are up to you. You could have `foo.js` be the name of the original source file and `foo.u.js` be the uglified one as long as you refer to the right names when loading.